# Detecting online status of device and sending back to server

Tags: android, push-notification, server, heartbeat

Hi I am developing android application in which I want show whether other person is online or not so that person can intiate the communication.I thought about few solution :

**1)** Implementing **heartbeat mechanism**, in which device will send ping request to server after fix interval of time.

**2)** Server will send **push type ping** to client and client will give response on that so that server will know that client is online.

First case causes battery and data issue, while  second one causes delay in push which will affect the process.

Is there any better solution for this problem? Apart from these or improvise version of above one.

Answer (score 2):

nilkash. Virtually any method for checking network connectivity will at the end result in sending periodical pings between device and the server. Even push type ping will actually do the same (but it saves battery because push notifications aggregate messages for all applications in-to a single connection to a google server). So the best solution is just a proper combination of optimizations and you have to choose them depending on your requests.

1. Server pushes are power efficient, mostly because they reuse the
   same connection for all applications, but the delay can be huge,
   something like 10 minutes.
2. You can subscribe to connectivity
   events and send "online" message to server once you are online. (But
   not once you are offline because you are... offline). This will give
   you immediate online events.
3. Do not send pings from device when there is no connectivity. Your application should be absolutely idle so as not to use battery.
4. There is no easy way to find out
   when client goes offline on server side. You have to trade
   traffic/battery for time resolution. More often you send pings, the
   better resolution is. But you can't change ping interval for pushes,
   so if you need better resolution, then you need to use your own
   connection. But you can send other useful data through that connection too.
5. If you keep a TCP connection, then your pings can be
   very data efficient: TCP keep alive packets are just 60/54 bytes.
   But then you have to keep open connections with all clients on the
   server. This may be a problem if you have a lot of clients.

The best combination may be something like that: you always send online message from a client when it becomes online. You keep TCP connection while the application is in foreground. You use the same connection to transfer data to and from the application. When your application goes to background you fallback to power consuming push based pings and do them at 10 minutes basis.

Comment: Great. If there is any sample code that would be better